# Visible Snapping Guidelines in Krita

Tags: snapping, krita, digital, python, smart-guides

I want to make the snapping guidelines visible like those in Photoshop for the Krita Digital Art Software. Does Krita have a settings option that I could make use of, if not how can I write an external python script which will enable me to do so?

Comment: Krita's Guides are well visible (if enabled in the view menu) as soon as one drags them out of the rulers. Do you expect something else?

Comment: Yes I need the lines which appear when snapping to center sideways, etc. with respect to certain image or canvas

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I have Krita 4.1.5 . Orthogonal and extension snapping guidelines are implemented there. Enable the snappings in the View > Snap To -menu. In the next image you see the guideline for extension snapping:

[image]

They work only with vector shapes. If I have a bitmap shape in a pixel layer, it's treated as whole layer. Its centerpoint can snap to guides, to image area horizontal and vertical center and to edges. But it doesn't see anything of the bitmap content of other pixel layers to snap. If I have a line in pixel layer, Krita doesn't calculate it's a line. It's only some pattern and the centerpoint of its layer is the only meaningful point that can snap.

How to program new functionality is unfortunately beyond my knowledge and the purpose of this site. You should join other programmers who have underhood knowledge of Krita.

Comment: Doesn’t that work for all objects?

Comment: @MrCrossCompile There's more in the answer.

Comment: Since, python plugins are supported in krita maybe someone can help who has programmed a similar script for themselves

Comment: Interpreted scripts are so far from bit level data processing that recognizing 1)there's a line in a bitmap layer and 2)snapping to it's extension is needed - is surely ineffective. If there's a clear shape edge surrounded by full transparency or you aim only a bounding box, you can succeed.